# How do I access a site's certificate for scraping with requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

In Python 3, I'm accessing a site with requests, to make a scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get('https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cposg/search.do?conversationId=&paginaConsulta=1&localPesquisa.cdLocal=-1&cbPesquisa=NMPARTE&tipoNuProcesso=UNIFICADO&dePesquisa=Alex+Spinelli+Manente&chNmCompleto=true&uuidCaptcha=')
```

But the error appears:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='esaj.tjsp.jus.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cposg/search.do?conversationId=&paginaConsulta=1&localPesquisa.cdLocal=-1&cbPesquisa=NMPARTE&tipoNuProcesso=UNIFICADO&dePesquisa=Alex+Spinelli+Manente&chNmCompleto=true&uuidCaptcha= (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),))
```

I understand that I need the site certificate, right?

Please, how do I download the site's certificate? I save this as .pem extension?

And how do I point to this file using the check option?

Comment: try `requests.get(url, verify=False)`

Comment: Thank you. But is this safe?

Comment: "InsecureRequestWarning"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not how to get the site's certificate. The site is presenting it to every client at every handshake.

If you open the web site in a browser, you'll get a human readable form of the error:

```
esaj.tjsp.jus.br uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates.
An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
```

When dealing with that error in the browser, you can view the offending certificate to check the issuer. It is:

```
CN = AC VALID BRASIL
OU = Autoridade Certificadora VALID - AC VALID
O = ICP-Brasil
C = BR
```

**If you trust** that authority, you need to obtain their signing certificate (not their website's certificate) to be able to verify the website. Save it to a file and pass the option `verify=/path/to/certfile` to `get()`. Read the full paragraph: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I see signing certificate? And then save it?

Comment: They almost certainly provide it for download on their website. But I don't speek portugese.

Comment: It is a website of a court of law. Hardly must exist, but thanks